# Error building Tensorflow C++ API from source [Windows 11]

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to build Tensorflow C++ API from source. I followed steps listed here:

- https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/error-building-tensorflow-2-8-in-windows-10/7984
- https://blog.devops.dev/btw-if-you-enjoy-my-tutorial-i-always-appreciate-endorsements-on-my-linkedin-https-www-linkedin-a6d6fcba1e44
- https://medium.com/vitrox-publication/deep-learning-frameworks-tensorflow-build-from-source-on-windows-python-c-cpu-gpu-d3aa4d0772d8

I followed similar steps for Windows 11 with CUDA 11.6.1 and cudnn 8.3.3 as listed in the first link.

I’ve been stuck on this for the past few days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Installed versions:
TensorFlow source, git branch r2.8
Windows 11
Cuda Toolkit 11.6.1
cuDNN 8.3.3
Bazel 4.2.1
Python 3.9.10
MSYS2 64bit
Visual Studio Community 2019
Nvidia RTX 1650Ti, compute capability 7.5

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_cuda':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/shrey/source/repos/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1401, column 38, in _cuda_autoconf_impl
                _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "C:/users/shrey/source/repos/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1239, column 56, in _create_local_cuda_repository
                host_compiler_includes + _cuda_include_path(
        File "C:/users/shrey/source/repos/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 364, column 32, in _cuda_include_path
                inc_entries.append(realpath(repository_ctx, cuda_config.cuda_toolkit_path + "/include"))
        File "C:/users/shrey/source/repos/tensorflow/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 290, column 19, in realpath
                return execute(repository_ctx, [bash_bin, "-c", "realpath \"%s\"" % path]).stdout.strip()
        File "C:/users/shrey/source/repos/tensorflow/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 230, column 13, in execute
                fail(
Error in fail: Repository command failed
```

Bazel build options:

```
--action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/shrey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
--action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/shrey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/site-packages 
--python_path=C:/Users/shrey/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
--action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.6 
--action_env CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=C:/Program Files/NVIDIA/CUDNN/v8.3 
--action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=7.5
--config=cuda --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions 
--host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions 
--define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true
```